# global declared variable is not visible in other module

Tags: node.js, global-variables

I'm declaring global variable as follows:

```
var NODE_MODULES_PATH = process.env.NODE_PATH || 'C:/Users/../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/';
    global.NODE_PATH = NODE_MODULES_PATH;
```

but when I'm accessing it in other module e.g. flollows:

```
var mysql = require(NODE_PATH + 'mysql');
```

it gives following error:

```
ReferenceError: NODE_PATH is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (z:\$app4pc\website_engine\conf\dbconnection.js:1:83)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (z:\$app4pc\website_engine\models\login_model.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js does not automatically put things in the global scope. You should export it from your module and require it in the one that uses it. If you must set a global variable, you can use:

```
var GLOBAL.NODE_MODULES_PATH = ...
```